# How to iterate over nested object query using ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to make a chat app using nodejs and mongodb. My question is how do i iterate or access the elements inside a nested object query returned by database?

My mongodb structure is like this:
**UPDATE**

```
{ 
"name": "Luxii",
"chat": {"text": "hello"},
{"text": "Wassup"}
}
```

This is for one User (i.e, one document).

My index.js code for querying the database is :

```
app.get('/welcome',function(req,res,result) {
console.log('in welcome');
db.collection('User').find().toArray(function(err,result){
if (err) throw err;
res.render('welcome.ejs',{user: result});
}); });
```

My welcome.ejs file has :

```
<body>
<class= "box" >
<% for(var i=0;i<user.length;i++){%>
<%= user[i].name %>:<%=user[i].chat%>

<%}%>
</class>
<form class="form" method="post" action="/chat">
<input type="text" placeholder="text" name="text">
<button type="submit">enter</button>
</form>
</body>
```

but the response that i get is :

Luxi: object Object

When i iterate my object like **user[i].chat[k].text** i get javascript error.

Comment: What is the JavaScript error? Also have you tried using `JSON.parse` t o parse the object before interacting with it?

Comment: @aug i have'nt tried JSON.parse yet.

Comment: @aug Javascript error is -- TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Comment: I suggest you to try the current instance type by `typeof` operator and if it return an object add another inside loop as well.

Comment: @ViranMalaka Now it returns  **Luxii:object** insted of **Luxii:objec Object**

Comment: @ViranMalaka What do you mean by "add another inside loop" ? can you elaborate please.

Comment: for() { if(condition){ for() } else{ [do your normal work] }} <-- please convert this pseudo code to ejs

Comment: @aug When I'm using JSON.parse as `var obj=JSON.parse(result);
res.render('welcome.ejs',{user: obj});`  i get this error `process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });`    `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

Comment: @ViranMalaka should i access the nested object array in second for loop then ? Like this : user[i].chat[k].text      ?

Comment: @lakshaygaur Yes, I think it will work

Comment: @ViranMalaka It says -- TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined